# Excel 2010 Sum of Values based on their month value and the current month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been looking all over for help with this, but not quite found what I'm looking for.

What I'm trying to do is add up the values of CREDIT (B2:B13) up to the current month and put that value in D2.

```
   A               B           C       D
 1 DATE            CREDIT              TOTAL AS OF TODAY
 2 15/01/2015      1000                4000
 3 15/02/2015      1000                
 4 15/03/2015      1000                
 5 15/04/2015      1000                
 6 15/05/2015      1000                
 7 15/06/2015      1000                
 8 15/07/2015      1000                
 9 15/08/2015      1000                
 10 15/09/2015     1000                
 11 15/10/2015     1000                
 12 15/11/2015     1000                
 13 15/12/2015     1000
```

For example: Lets say the current date is 30th April 2015. Sum all the values in B2:B13 up to today's date based on their date value from the Date column (A2:A13). So D2 should = 4000.

I'm quite new to Excel so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: That's a very good question. So on May 15th, I'd expect it to be 5000. But on May 14th, I'd expect it to remain at 4000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMIF` should do the trick ([documentation here](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/SUMIF-function-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ))

So D2's formula would be:

```
=SUMIF($A2:$A13,"<"&Today(),$B$2:$B$13)
```

The first argument is the range you want to test.  The second argument is the condition you want to test for.  The last argument is the range that you want to add up if the test passes.